# C socket: recv and send all data

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, send, recv

I would like to obtain a behavior similar to this:

1. Server run
2. Client run
3. Client type a command like "help" or other
4. Server responds appropriately
5. go to 3

The problem is that when my function excCommand("help") run just a little text is received and printed.
My text file is this:

```
COMMAND HELP:

help - Display help
quit - Shutdown client
```

only COMMAND HELP is printed.
Another problem is that when i type a command nothing is printed and after 2 command client exit.
This is the piece in particular:

```
while (quit)
    {
        getLine("client> ", command, 10);
        if (strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
            quit = 0;
        else
            excCommand(command);
    }
```

This is the server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "common.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        ErrorWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)", "<Server Port>");

    char *service = argv[1];

    int servSock = SetupTCPServerSocket(service);
    if (servSock < 0)
        ErrorWithUserMessage("SetupTCPServerSocket() failed: ", "unable to establish");

    unsigned int childProcessCount = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int clntSock = AcceptTCPConnection(servSock);

        pid_t processID = fork();
        if (processID < 0)
            ErrorWithSystemMessage("fork() failed");
        else if (processID == 0)
        {
            close(servSock);
            HandleTCPClient(clntSock);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        printf("with child process: %d\n", processID);
        close(clntSock);
        childProcessCount++;

        //clean up zombies
        while (childProcessCount)
        {
            processID = waitpid((pid_t) - 1, NULL, WNOHANG);
            if (processID < 0)
                ErrorWithSystemMessage("waitpid() failed");
            else if (processID == 0)
                break;
            else
                childProcessCount--;
        }

    }

}
```

Handler:

```
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSock)
{
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t numBytesRcvd = recv(clntSock, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
    buffer[numBytesRcvd] = '\0';
    if (numBytesRcvd < 0)
        ErrorWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
    if (strcmp(buffer, "help") == 0)
    {
        FILE *fp = fopen("help.txt", "r");
        if (fp)
        {
            char line[128];
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
            {
                if (send(clntSock, line, sizeof(line), 0) < 0)
                    ErrorWithSystemMessage("send() failed");
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    close(clntSock);
}
```

and this is my client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include "common.h"

int sock;

void getLine(char *message, char *buf, int maxLen)
{
    printf("%s", message);
    fgets(buf, maxLen, stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = 0;
}

void excCommand(char *command)
{
    if ( send(sock, command, strlen(command), 0) < 0)
        ErrorWithSystemMessage("send() failed");

    char replyMessage[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t numBytesRecv = 0;
    do
    {
        numBytesRecv = recv(sock, replyMessage, BUFSIZE, 0);
        if ( numBytesRecv < 0)
            ErrorWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
        printf("%s\n", replyMessage);
        memset(&replyMessage, 0, sizeof(replyMessage));

    }
    while (numBytesRecv > 0);
}

void PrintFile(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp)
    {
        char line[128];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
            fputs(line, stdout);
        fputs("\n", stdout);
        fclose(fp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int quit = 1;
    char command[10];

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        ErrorWithUserMessage("Parameter(s)", "<Server Address> <Server Port>");
    }

    char *server = argv[1];
    char *service = argv[2];

    sock = SetupTCPClientSocket(server, service);
    if (sock < 0)
        ErrorWithUserMessage("SetupTCPClientSocket() failed: ", "unable to connect");

    printf("Connection established!\n\n");

    PrintFile("menu.txt");
    excCommand("help");

    while (quit)
    {
        getLine("client> ", command, 10);
        if (strcmp(command, "quit") == 0)
            quit = 0;
        else
            excCommand(command);
    }

    fputs("\n", stdout);
    close(sock);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

sorry for being so long-winded

Comment: Next time you have a question, try to build a program as small as possible that simulates similar behavior, it will be much easier for people to understand what the problem is and to help you.

Comment: you're right, sorry for this :(

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `recv()` and `send()` functions do not guarantee to send/recv all data (see [man recv](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), [man send](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send))

You need to implement your own `send_all()` and `recv_all()`, something like

```
bool send_all(int socket, void *buffer, size_t length)
{
    char *ptr = (char*) buffer;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int i = send(socket, ptr, length);
        if (i < 1) return false;
        ptr += i;
        length -= i;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The following guide may help you [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: ok but on the other side, how do I know how many times I have to call recv ()?

Comment: You can add the length of the message before each message. And recv() fixed number of bytes representing the length of the message size, and then call recv(message_size)

Comment: This send_all() function does not work. It should declare 'buffer' as 'char *'; it should increment 'buffer' by 'i' every time 'i' is positive; and of course it should stop altogether if 'i' is negative.

Comment: And the whole thing is unnecessary. The `send()` method blocks until all data has been transferred or an error occurs. In blocking mode of course, but that's what this code assumes. A non-blocking implementation would have to use `select()` to know when to write next.

Answer (score 3):

Usual problems.

```
void excCommand(char *command)
{
    if ( send(sock, command, strlen(command), 0) < 0)
        ErrorWithSystemMessage("send() failed");

    char replyMessage[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t numBytesRecv = 0;
    do
    {
        numBytesRecv = recv(sock, replyMessage, BUFSIZE, 0);
        if ( numBytesRecv < 0)
            ErrorWithSystemMessage("recv() failed");
        printf("%s\n", replyMessage);
```

Invalid. `numBytesRecv` could have been zero, in which case there is no message at all, otherwise at this point must be positive, as you've already tested for negative, and it indicates the actual length of the message, which isn't necessarily null-terminated. Change to:

```
    if (numBytesRecv == 0)
        break;
    printf("%.*s\n", numBytesRecv, replyMessage);
```

and then:

```
        memset(&replyMessage, 0, sizeof(replyMessage));
```

Pointless. Remove.

```
    }
    while (numBytesRecv > 0);
```

At this point you should check for `numBytesRecv < 0` and call `perror()` or one of its friends.

Answer (score -1):

I choose to send before each send() if i have to continue or not.

so i first have 3 define

```
#define BUFFSIZE 1024
#define CONT "CONT"
#define DONE "DONE"
```

Then to send my data

```
int     send_to_socket(int sock, char *msg)
{
    size_t  len;
    int     ret[2];

    len = strlen(msg);
    ret[0] = send(sock, (len <= BUFFSIZE) ? DONE : CONT, 4, 0);
    ret[1] = send(sock, msg, BUFFSIZE, 0);
    if (ret[0] <= 0 || ret[1] <= 0)
    {
        perror("send_to_socket");
        return (-1);
    }
    if (len > BUFFSIZE)
        return (send_to_socket(sock, msg + BUFFSIZE));
    return (1);
}
```

And to receive it :

```
char    *recv_from_socket(int cs)
{
    char    state[5];
    char    buff[BUFFSIZE+1];
    char    *msg;
    int     ret[2];

    msg = NULL;
    while (42)
    {
        bzero(state, 5);
        bzero(buff, BUFFSIZE+1);
        ret[0] = recv(cs, state, 4, 0);
        ret[1] = recv(cs, buff, BUFFSIZE, 0);
        if (ret[0] <= 0 || ret[1] <= 0)
        {
            perror("recv_from_socket");
            return (NULL);
        }
        // strfljoin() is selfmade
        // join the string and free the left argument to prevent memory leaks.
        // return fresh new string
        msg = (msg) ? ft_strfljoin(msg, buff) : strdup(buff);
        if (strncmp(state, DONE, 4) == 0)
            break ;
        i++;
    }
    return (msg);
}
```

Comment: links to strfljoin() : https://github.com/ale-batt/libft/blob/master/sources/string/ft_strjoin.c