# WinError: 10054 (0x2746) An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. TCP Server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, winsock

I have the client side in C# running from Unity and it's just this

```
byte[] buffer = { 1 };
Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(IP, PORT);
System.Int32 Result = s.Send(buffer);
Debug.Log(Result);
```

and the server side is written in C, it's really long so here is the place where I get the error

```
for(char i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; ++i)
{
            if(ClientSockets[i] == INVALID_SOCKET) break;
            

            Result = recv(ClientSockets[i], Message, sizeof(Message), 0);
            
            if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                unsigned long LastError = GetLastError();
                if (LastError != 10035)
                {
                    Error("recv failed.\n");
                }
            }
```

I've made the socket's non blocking with `ioctlsocket(ClientSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode)` before putting them in the ClientSockets array.

Comment: What is IP and PORT?   There is a few reasons why you get this error message.  One common reason is if the IP address is the loopback 127.0.0.1 and you use Send() method.  Why your client and server are on the same machine you  have to make sure the listener and sender do not use the same IP.  So you use for listener IP.Any and client you use IP address of the machine.

Comment: @jdweng the ip is "192.168.1.100" and the port is 7042

Comment: Does this answer your question: [C socket: recv and send all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479760/c-socket-recv-and-send-all-data) ? -> Accepted answer states: `The recv() and send() functions do not guarantee to send/recv all data (see man recv, man send)`

Comment: Check from cmd.exe>Netstat -a and see if port is already used. The listener must be started before client.  If on same machine the listener cannot use IP 192.168.1.100.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. My problem was that the socket on the client side was created inside a function so it disappeared after the function finished executing.