# I got some strange word 'Received: 艎��' in socket program

Tags: c, sockets

I wrote a server program and a client program that communicate with sockets on linux ubuntu. The client program outputs `Received: 艎��`

This my server code:

```
/*** tcp_server.c ***/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
    int sock_fd, new_fd, bytes;
    struct sockaddr_in seraddr, cliaddr;
    char data[1024];
    socklen_t cli_addr_size;
    cli_addr_size = sizeof(cliaddr);

    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&seraddr, 0, sizeof(seraddr));
    seraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    seraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // INADDR_ANY : It received Network Interface that connected server defined interface, htonl :  
    seraddr.sin_port = htons(5050);
    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&seraddr, sizeof(seraddr));
    listen(sock_fd, 10);
    while (1) {
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &cli_addr_size);
        bytes = recv(new_fd, data, 1024, 0);
        send(new_fd, data, bytes, 0);
        close(new_fd);
    }   

    close(sock_fd);
}
```

My client code is:

```
/*** tcp_client.c ***/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock_fd, bytes;
    struct sockaddr_in ser_addr;
    char *snddata, rcvdata[1024];

    snddata = argv[2];
    sock_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&ser_addr, 0,sizeof(ser_addr));
    ser_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ser_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]); // INADDR_ANY : It received Network Interface that connected server defined interface, htonl :  
    ser_addr.sin_port = htons(5050);
    connect(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&ser_addr, sizeof(ser_addr));
    send(sock_fd, snddata, strlen(snddata), 0);
    printf("Received: ");
    
    bytes = recv(sock_fd, rcvdata, 1024, 0);
    rcvdata[bytes] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", rcvdata);

    close(sock_fd);
}
```

First I got an error for argument 3 of `accept`, then I changed

```
        new_fd = accept(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr);
```

But It still produces this strange word.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your *send()* and *receive()* functions so that you have full control over how much and **which** byte you send from the buffer (`data[1024]`) like in this thread : [C socket: recv and send all data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479760/c-socket-recv-and-send-all-data) and also see *Beej's Guide to Network Programming* (**http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/**)

Also make sure that you initialize your data buffers:

```
data[1024] = "";
rcvdata[1024] = "";
```

or

```
 data[1024];
 data[0] = '\0';
 rcvdata[1024];
 rcvdata[0] = '\0';
```

, background is in this thread :  [Why I am getting this unusually symbols by printing char string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66611875/why-i-am-getting-this-unusually-symbols-by-printing-char-string)