# Why am I getting these unusual symbols when printing a string?

Tags: c

I am trying to separate date/month/year from a string into multiple variables.
When I try to print them I get unknown symbols.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char string[40];
    char tempm[10], tempd[10], tempy[10];
    int month, date, year;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Introduceti data: \n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", string);
    for (int i = 0; i <strlen(string); i++){
      if (string[i] == '/'){
        count ++;
      }
      else{
        if (count == 0){
            strncat(tempm, &string[i], 1);
        }
        if (count == 1){
            strncat(tempd, &string[i],1);
        }
        if (count == 2){
            strncat(tempy, &string[i], 1);
        }
      }
    }
        printf("%s",tempm);
    }
```

And this is the output:

```
Introduceti data: 
11/12/21
Y��U11
```

How to delete 'Y��U'?

Comment: You have to initialize your `temp*` arrays before you use them with `strncat`.

Comment: How to do that ? I am newbie in C ..

Comment: `char tempm[10] = "", tempd[10] = "", tempy[10] = "";`

Comment: char temp[10] = "";

Comment: out of that you can write ouf of any of your arrays, because you do not limit at scan time, then in *tempxx* whose are smaller than *string*

Comment: Thank you.
Now I have a variable char tempm[10], and I want to put it in an if condition, for example:
if (temp == '1' ){
char month[20] = 'January'
}
How to do that correct ?

Comment: Note that `" %[^\n]s"` is a beginner's hybrid of `" %[^\n]"` and `"%s"`.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not initialised by default in C. You then need to explicitly provide a value for them before using it, like:

```
tempm[0] = '\0';
```

which will set `tempm` to the empty C-string. Or at the very same time of the definition:

```
char tempm[10] = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters these arrays

```
char tempm[10], tempd[10], tempy[10];
```

are not initialized and have indeterminate values. So they do not contain strings. But the function `strncat` supposes that the destination array contains a string. So calls like this

```
strncat(tempm, &string[i], 1);
```

result in undefined behavior.

You need to initialize the arrays like for example

```
char tempm[10] = "", tempd[10] = "", tempy[10] = "";
```

In fact there is no need to split a string into substrings. Instead you could use the standard C function `strtol` applied directly to the original string.

Comment: `strncat` manual says *As with strcat(), the resulting string in dest is always null-terminated.*